# Show Pincode/shipping availability checker in magento 2 header

Tags: magento2, php-7, design, zipcode, pincodes

I have implemented Pincode checker in Magento 2 product detail page by creating a custom module, but I need to show it in the header section and hide it from the product detail page. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please share xml file code?

Comment: Currently, I put it under the main menu, but how can put it at the end of the menu near contact us. 
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
       <block class="Vendor\CheckDelivery\Block\Product\View\CheckDelivery" name="zipcode" before="-" template="Vendor_CheckDelivery::product/view/check_delivery.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>

Comment: Ok, then try the following:
<referenceContainer name="footer-container"><block class="Vendor\CheckDelivery\Block\Product\View\CheckDelivery" name="zipcode" after="-" template="Vendor_CheckDelivery::product/view/check_delivery.phtml"/> </referenceContainer>

Comment: I will try it above code, but it showing at the end of the footer section. But I need to show it in the main menu section.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please try this one: <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper"> <block class="Vendor\CheckDelivery\Block\Product\View\CheckDelivery" name="zipcode" after="-" template="Vendor_CheckDelivery::product/view/check_delivery.phtml"/> </referenceContainer>

Comment: It is showing below the menu section and if I navigate product list page it will go near the footer section.  But I need near the menu section or need to show below the icon.